# Twoside option add unwanted blank vertical spaces

Tags: double-sided

After add twoside parameter I got white spaces between some elements. I create an overleaf example https://www.overleaf.com/read/tfbpqxtrqpjz

You can see that adding twoside parameter will add blank vertical spaces.

How can I use twoside and openright parameters without adding the blank vertical space?

[image]

Comment: I'm sure that this issue has been discussed in earlier postings. The `report`  and `book` document classes use the setting `\flushbottom` if the `twoside` document class option is active. To override this setting, issue the instruction `\raggedbottom` immediately after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Reasoning behind this: Distribute the text over the whole page evenly to have the same bottom *"margin"* on all pages.